# How to use withAnimation in a Rectangle on SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui

Im trying to adapt the animation to my rectangle, I just don't know how.
I got in my view a `Rectangle` that appears when the screen shows up and I got this warning:

> 'animation' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use withAnimation or animation(_:value:) instead.

```
Rectangle()
     .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.6))
     .foregroundColor(.green)
     .frame(width: 20, height: max(10, alturas.0))
     .cornerRadius(6)
```

I tried like this

```
Rectangle()
     .foregroundColor(.green)
     .frame(width: 20, height: max(10, alturas.0))
     .cornerRadius(6)
     .onAppear{
          withAnimation{
               .easeInOut(duration: 0.6)
          }
     }
```

Comment: What aspect of the rectangle do you want to animate? Its height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are controlling the animation using a tuple. Maybe it is defined something like this:

```swift
typealias Alturas = (CGFloat, CGFloat)
@State private var alturas: Alturas = (0, 0)
```

So to get rid of the deprecation warning, you just need to add `value` as a parameter to the `.animation` modifier, like this:

```swift
Rectangle()
    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.6), value: alturas.0)
    // other modifiers as before
```

Alternatively, you can remove the `.animation` modifier completely and perform the update `withAnimation`, like this:

```swift
Rectangle()
    .foregroundColor(.green)
    .frame(width: 20, height: max(10, alturas.0))
    .cornerRadius(6)
    .onAppear {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 6)) {
            alturas.0 = 100
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the new values within the `withAnimation` block to expect those changes to be animated. For instance like this:

```
@State private var rectangleWidth: CGFloat = 0

var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.green)
        .frame(width: rectangleWidth, height: rectangleWidth)
        .cornerRadius(6)
        .onAppear(perform: {
            withAnimation {
                rectangleWidth = 20
            }
        })
}
```

This will make the rectangle start with size (0, 0) and once it appears it will increase its size to (20, 20).